# Saving a Drawing but not a Full Image in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I'm working on making a paint-esq image manipulator in VB.Net, and I'm still new to vb. I want the user to be able to upload an image and make adjustments to it, such as adding lines and text. I also want the user to be able to transfer the drawings and text they added to a different baseimage. For example, if the user draws a dog on top of a picture of a park, they can change it so the dog is on a street instead.

I've been messing with the idea of loading the image as the picturebox.backgroundImage, but running into difficulties changing the backgroundImage without reseting the drawings and with croping the image. I've also been dabling in having two pictureboxes with the one on top for drawings, but I'm running into transparency and cropping issues

Here is the code I'm using to establish my picturebox by setting the base image as .backgroundImage

```
Private Sub LoadImage(thisImage As Image)

    'we set the picturebox size according to image, we can get image width and height with the help of Image.Width and Image.height properties.
    img.BackgroundImage = thisImage 'c'
    img.Image = New Bitmap(thisImage.Width, thisImage.Height) 'c'

    img.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
  End Sub
```

example of the image maniputlation

```
 Private Sub ButtonDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDone.Click, DoneToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Select Case LCase(stateFlag)
        Case "header"
            'Reset stuff back to normal
            ButtonHeader.Text = "Header"
            stateFlag = ""
            Cancel_Button.Enabled = False

            'set up space to draw on the image
            Dim newBm As New Bitmap(img.Image.Width, img.Image.Height)

             ' First we define a rectangle with the help of already calculated points 
            Dim newGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBM) ' create graphics 
            newGraphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            newGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
            newGraphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality

            'set image attributes 
            newGraphics.DrawImage(img.Image, New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Image.Width + 1, img.Image.Height + 1), _
                      0, 0, img.Image.Width + 1, img.Image.Height + 1, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            'Draw Edges for header

            newGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, startPoint.X, borderSize - 20, startPoint.X, borderSize - 50)
            newGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, endPoint.X, borderSize - 20, endPoint.X, borderSize - 50)

            Dim drawFont As New Font("Times New Roman", 12)
            Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            Dim stringSize As SizeF = newGraphics.MeasureString(HeaderLabel.Text, drawFont)
            ' Draw header label inbetween the two edges.
            newGraphics.DrawString(HeaderLabel.Text, drawFont, drawBrush, (startPoint.X + endPoint.X) / 2 - (stringSize.Width / 2), borderSize - 45)

            img.Image = newBm
            PushUndo(img.Image.Clone)
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you post the code and explain the issues?  These kind of questions are often difficult to give a specific answer otherwise, please [check this out](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).  I do see a good example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hirendra_singh/image-editing-tool-in-VB-Net-part-11/) which seems along the lines of what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what functions would best illustrate the issues. I uploaded some representative code

Comment: sounds generally like you want to save multiple images - analogous to the Layers that photoshop implements (assuming you **have** the dog and park as individual images)

Comment: I've been having issues with the transparency with I have the baseimage as one picture box and the drawings as another picture box on top, (The top picture box blocks out the bottom one with it's whiteness) but I'll explore that more.

Comment: the problem is not with the transparency.  floating one picbox over another does not mean the bottom image will show thru.  the parent control for each is the form, so the it is the form which is showing thru because to Win/NET it is the form which is "behind" each of them.  the PictureBox lacks a `Controls()` collection so you cant add other picboxes to a bottom for them to act like you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise trying the following method to use one `picturebox` on top of the other, it is a lot simpler than some other methods. In your **form load handler**, do something like:

```
pctBackground.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromFile("park.jpg")
pctForeground.BackColor = Color.Transparent
pctForeground.Parent = pctBackground
pctForeground.Image = New Bitmap(pctForeground.ClientSize.Width, pctForeground.ClientSize.Height)
```

Then when you have drawn on the `pctForeground`, save it like:

```
pctForeground.Image.Save("dog_in_park.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```